# How to simplify this sequence

Tags: signal-analysis, convolution, homework

So I had this question (f) at my last exam that I failed and I'm now studying for my re-exam, the problem is that I still don't know what the answer is supposed to be in this question (f):

[image: Question]

[image: My attempt]

Do you have any suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: Hint: you do understand that $*$ is convolution, not multiplication?

Comment: Yes, but the convolution is supposed to be distributive so the first step should be correct.
The second assumption is wrong but now looking at it I would say that the answer should be X(n)-X(n-1) based on that the dirac delta only giving a value to X(n) when n=0.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Well $\delta(n)*x(n)*u(n)$ doesn't equal $x(n)$. Apart from that, you are correct.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what it would equal then :/
 δ(n)∗x(n) from what I understand is x(n) but I don't understand what effect that d(n) would have except for limiting the possible answer to n>0

Comment: OK. So $u(n)$ is the unit step. $x(n)u(n)$ limits $x(n)$ to times $n>0$.  However, we are dealing with $x(n)*u(n)$ (convolution not multiplication).

Comment: So from what I understand X(n) convoluted by U(n) should give U(n)X(n-k)?

Comment: Not quite. [Check out Example 1 in Part II of this.](http://courses.washington.edu/bioen316/Assignments/316_SCP.pdf)

Comment: So now I understand, the d(n-k) sets the limits while being convoluted since the dirac while convoluted isn't fixed to a specific position.
I.E. I get u(n)d(n-k) which gives u(n-k).
In the end u(n)-u(n-1) = d(n) which convoluted by x(n) gives x(n).
Correct?

Comment: Any chance for LaTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

The only thing you need to know is that any sequence convolved with a (shifted) delta impulse is a shifted version of itself:

$$f[n]*\delta[n-k]=f[n-k]$$

Apply this to the expression $u[n]*(\delta[n]-\delta[n-1])$, and realize that what you're left with is a very simple sequence. (The result of (a) will be helpful.)

Then convolve this very simple sequence with $x[n]$ to get the final result.

Comment: Too much information!!! ;-)  (And +1)

Comment: Thanks for the help.
u(n)-u(n-1) = d(n) and convoluted by x(n) gives x(n).
I think both of you guys helped widening my perception of the convolution!

Comment: @ricksson Glad to hear it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
x(n)*[d(n)-d(n-1)]=x(n)*d(n)-x(n)*d(n-1)
                              = x(n)-x(n-1)
```